# Theme menu link differently by region

Tags: theming

I want to override theme menu link items in my theme.
I know that I must use `theme_menu_link(array $variables)` theme function.

But I want to know, is there any way that I can change the output render of theme_menu_link function based on region.

for example if menu link item is located in **header** region, it must be wrapped in `div` tag and if menu link item is located in **footer** region, it must be wrapped in `li` tag.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use CSS to change how the links look in each region? What is your end goal?

Comment: yes, there is. because in header menu are simple li tag but in footer menu item includes some images and info that are loaded from database. so in second case, I need to run some codes that fetch data from database.

Comment: Do it by targeting specific menus:https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77714/how-to-add-attributes-to-menu-and-menu-items-on-the-block-level-in-theme-preproc#77721